# C# read C code like (%d into number)

Tags: c#

I have bunch of script that use C/C++ style coding, for example:
`img_sequence_%06d.tiff`. This will create a range from `img_sequence_000000.tiff` until `img_sequence_999999.tiff`

so, how to read `%d` in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by read?

Comment: read or create with number with 6 digits?

Comment: string st = string.Format("{0:000000}", 123 );

Comment: @BondaryukVladimir - close, I think what would work better is string.Format("img_sequence_{0:000000}.tiff", xxx) where xxx is the variable for the loop counter.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, you are right :)

Comment: I have problem with many scripts to deal with, because all using C/C++ style placeholder, to list number, need c# to understand `%d`

Comment: Obviously you've already did your search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sprintf, but maybe you've missed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19274/A-printf-implementation-in-C (which I assume you are looking for). For future question please show what you've already found and clearly specify what you have/expect and what you already tried/how it is not working.

Comment: I not mean to `%d` = `{0:000000}`. I wanted my program read a file that contain `%d`, for example: `ImageSource("img_sequence_%06d.tiff", 000000, 000124, 25).FlipVertical()` <- a avs script... so, how to make C# understand `%d`

Answer (score 2):

```
int number = 1;
string name = string.Format("img_sequence_{0:000000}.tiff", number);
```

name will img_sequence_000001.tiff

Comment: Use `D6` instead, it scales better.

Comment: C#6 `$"img_sequence_{number:d6}.tiff"`

Answer (score 0):

The `%d` specifier indicates a placeholder for a decimal number.  The width on that suggests it's a 6 digit number.  That seems like a perfect case for a regular expression.  Match on the digits and parse it to an integer.

```
var re = new Regex(@"img_sequence_(\d{6})\.tiff");
var m = re.Match("img_sequence_123456.tiff");
if (m.Success)
{
    var sequence = Int32.Parse(m.Group[1].Value); // 123456
    // do something with sequence
}
```

Comment: I'd avoid Regex when possible. In this case, you could do `int.Parse(string.Replace("img_sequence_", "").Replace(".tiff", ""))` since format is known. In any case, this has 0 relevance to the OP's question, which is about generating the names, rather than matching them.

Comment: Your suggestion is worse.  There are far more readable ways to extract a part of a string _and_ validate at the same time.  But a regex is a bit overkill here I'll give you that.  Regarding the question, when I see the word `read`, generating a string is not the first thing I would think of. Maybe that's what he meant in the end, but it's not like it has been clarified.

Comment: `s.Substring(s.IndexOf('.') - 6, 6)`

Comment: Or maybe very readable even as `new string(s.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit))` - It really spells out the logic